# How to use Drupal Captcha in Custom form?

Tags: captcha

Creating nodes can take a long time. That is why for one specific part of my site, I have created my own custom form. The problem is, I want to use the captcha plugin so I don't have to get another separate module for that.

How can I use the Captcha module PROGRAMATICALLY so that I don't need a separate libary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the code in the [Captcha](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module, it looks like Captcha defines a new form element.

So an example would look like:

```
$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Name'),
);
$form['captcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'captcha/Math',
);
```

Where `captcha/Math` is the module that provides a type of captcha, followed by the type of captcha to use.

Comment: and how can I set the refresh button?